# Retrieve specific row from database and display all the data in the specific row and send json using php

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli, header

I would like to retrieve a specific row from database using php and mysqli.

For example:

I want to retrieve the row of data with userid =2

```
$userid =2;
```

Then I get it the user email, name, password from database using the $userid given:

```
include("includes/connect.php");
$user = "SELECT * FROM account WHERE user_id = $userid " ;
$query = mysqli_query ($conn,  $user);        

while($result = mysqli_fetch_array ($query)){
      $name = $result['username'];
      $password = $result['user_password']; 
      $email = $result['user_email'];           
  }
```

Then I would like to send the username, password and email of the userid=2 to mobile app in json.

How can I do that after that?

Comment: you got some advance with your problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass data with `json_encode`:

```
$data = array();
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array ($query)){
  $data['username'] = $result['username'];
  $data['user_password'] = $result['user_password']; 
  $data['user_email'] = $result['user_email'];           
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Also you can use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` for retrieving json data from database:

```
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)
echo json_encode($row);
```

[More information about `mysqli_fetch_assoc` function.](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_assoc.asp)

Note, If you are sure that just one row will return(In this case I think just one row will return, because usually user_id is unique), no need to use `while`.

Answer (score 1):

First you need add this line  `header('Content-Type: application/json');`
 to output your json file to the browser, and see the change in your `while` loop, and call the function `json_encode()`

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

include("includes/connect.php");
$user = "SELECT * FROM account WHERE user_id = $userid " ;
$query = mysqli_query ($conn,  $user);        

$json = array();

while($result = mysqli_fetch_array ($query)){
      $json['name'] = $result['username'];
      $json['password'] = $result['user_password']; 
      $json['email'] = $result['user_email'];           
  }

echo json_encode($json);
```

Read mote at:

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php